# stop html() from encoding tags in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I got this [text editor](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxmaf/560/) from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120809/possible-to-populate-and-save-text-entered-from-inside-a-iframe-in-designmode). The editor is an iframe so in order to get the html content from the iframe body by this line on submit click

```
    $('#submit').click(function(){
      var see =  $("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html();
      console.log(see)
    });
```

While using `html()`, any html tags or script tags will be encoded as shown in the console. It wouldn't be a problem normally but I'm starting to use HTML purifier to sanitize input data. The encoded string will not be recognized by the purifier and let any tags pass into the database as something like `&lt;script&gt;alert('Hello');&lt;/script&gt;rtrrttr`. 
Does anyone have any solutions to stop `html()` from encoding tags?

Comment: this shouldnt be by design, html would return `<` instead of `&lt;`

Comment: Very strange. would that be the iframe problem?

Comment: as it seems, maybe yes